# Is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n! \ne 0$ in every $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, p-adic-number-theory

Is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n! \ne 0$  in every $\mathbb{Q}_p$? I read that this was an open problem but the answer seemed obvious that it should be true since after the term p! every term added on will be small and not affect the previous digits to the right.

Comment: Are you sure that $\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}n!$ is not divisible by $p$? If it is, then the terms $n!$, $n=p,p+1,\ldots,2p-1,$ may still affect the most significant digit

Comment: Ah yeah that's what I was overlooking thanks haha.

Comment: It is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^{pN-1} n! \equiv 0 \bmod p^{\sum_{k \ge 1} \lfloor N / p^k \rfloor}$ for every $N$

Comment: Mind you, I checked the primes $p<1000$ with Mathematica. Unless I made a mistake, $p=2$ was the only case when $\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}n!\equiv0\pmod p$. Of course, $p=2$ is not a counterexample as $\sum_{n=0}^3n!=10$ is not divisible by eight, but from that point on all the other terms of the series are.